# Find rows in dataframe where column value is different from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 & df2. They have the same column names and usually the same column values. I need to isolate the rows where the value in the column was changed, and add a column to signify what the previous value was.

In the example below, the number of actions for Nancy changes between df1 and df2. I want to create a new dataframe with just that row, even though a new row for Mary was added to df2.

df1:

| Name | Action | Number of Actions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stacy | Action1 | 32 |
| Nancy | Action2 | 67 |
| Emily | Action3 | 89 |
| Abby | Action2 | 9 |

df2:

| Name | Action | Number of Actions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stacy | Action1 | 32 |
| Nancy | Action2 | 75 |
| Emily | Action3 | 89 |
| Abby | Action2 | 9 |
| Mary | Action1 | 43 |

Expected Output (as a dataframe):

| Name | Action | Number of Actions | Previous Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nancy | Action2 | 75 | 67 |

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
df = (df2.merge(df1, on=['Name', 'Action'], how='left')
      .rename(columns={'Number of Actions_x': 'Number of Actions', 'Number of Actions_y': 'Previous Value'})
      .loc[lambda df: df['Number of Actions'].ne(df['Previous Value'])]
      .dropna()
      )
```

```
print(df)

    Name   Action  Number of Actions  Previous Value
1  Nancy  Action2                 75              67
```

Comment: Nice! For the selection step, you could also do ``.query('`Number of Actions` != `Previous Value`')`` instead.